# I don't understand how to fix this error i am trying to deploying my contract with python

Tags: contract-design, smart-contract-wallets

This is my code please help, I am busting my head for 2 hours
I have installed many libraries, I don't know if I am doing it wrong or what

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

with open("SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()


# Solidity source code
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="v0.6.0",
)

print (compiled_sol)
```

[image: please help me with code]

Comment: Please add the code here, since the error says the error is on ;ln7 but it means somehting between those parenthesis, not that line per se

Answer (score 1):

thank god... i finally solved it.
It is just like hiding in the plain sight, **what I have done is just uninstall the py-solc-x and reinstall it** and....
it worked.

hope if someone facing this issue could also use this method.